# How to get two different select box values and show a result based on combination of values in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, variables, select, compare

I need to show the user a different result (picture) based on the combination of day and month they select.
Example: if you select day 1 and month 3, you will get an alert based on your selection, if you select day 03 and month 6 you get a different result, etc.
This is what I managed to do now:

Like this I can get two variables from the two selected values
but can't get a result from comparing variable m with variable d, because they are inside
two different functions. But they need to be in two different functions in order to be
called onChange in each select box, right?
What would be a good solution to this?
Thanks

`````
<select class="sb"  id="day" onChange='getDay(this);'>
                                <option value="">Day</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                            </select>
                      
                            <select class="sb"  id="month" onChange='getMonth(this);' >
                                <option value="">Month</option>
                                <option value="1">Jan</option>
                                <option value="2">Feb</option>
                                <option value="3">Mar</option>
                                <option value="4">Apr</option>
                                <option value="5">May</option>
                                <option value="6">Jun</option>
                                <option value="7">Jul</option>
                                <option value="8">Aug</option>
                                <option value="9">Sep</option>
                                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                <option value="12">Dec</option>
                            </select>


    function getDay(sel) {
                        var d = (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
                        if (d == "01"){
                            console.log("day 1");
                        }
                    }
    
    
         function gethMonth(sel) {
                        var m = (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
                        if (m == "Jan"){
                            console.log("January");
                        }
                    }````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getData(e) {
  var d = document.getElementById("day").value
  var m = document.getElementById("month").value
  
  // Do whatever you want with your two variables d and m
  // for example console.log them
  console.log(d + "." + m);
}
```

```html
<select class="sb"  id="day" onChange='getData()'>
   <option value="">Day</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
   <option value="03">03</option>
   <option value="04">04</option>
   <option value="05">05</option>
   <option value="06">06</option>
   <option value="07">07</option>
   <option value="08">08</option>
   <option value="09">09</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
                      
<select class="sb"  id="month" onChange='getData()' >
   <option value="">Month</option>
   <option value="1">Jan</option>
   <option value="2">Feb</option>
   <option value="3">Mar</option>
   <option value="4">Apr</option>
   <option value="5">May</option>
   <option value="6">Jun</option>
   <option value="7">Jul</option>
   <option value="8">Aug</option>
   <option value="9">Sep</option>
   <option value="10">Oct</option>
   <option value="11">Nov</option>
   <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```